# Migration from RestEasy to RestEasyReactive with ResteasyContext and ContainerRequestFilter

Tags: java, jax-rs, quarkus, resteasy

I'm migrating old Quarkus project from RestEasy to ResteasyReactive and I have some difficulties migrating `ResteasyContext.pushContext` since there is no real 1:1 alternative in rest easy.

I'm using the `ResteasyContext.pushContext` in my `ContainerRequestFilter` to push some custom object to Context and later retrieve it using @Context.

Something like in this minimal example i provided.

Filter:

```
package org.acme.filter;

import org.acme.pojo.CustomHttpRequest;
import org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResteasyContext;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Random;

@Provider
@ApplicationScoped
public class HttpRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
        CustomHttpRequest request = CustomHttpRequest.builder()
                .headers(requestContext.getHeaders())
                .dateTime(LocalDateTime.now())
                .text("Some random text for example " + new Random().nextInt(100))
                .build();
        ResteasyContext.pushContext(CustomHttpRequest.class, request);
    }
}
```

Custom object I want to push to context:

```
package org.acme.pojo;

import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.ToString;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Getter
@Builder
@ToString
public class CustomHttpRequest {

    private String text;
    private LocalDateTime dateTime;
    private MultivaluedMap<String, String> headers;
    private boolean secured;
}
```

And the later read it from context in my rest endpoint:

```
package org.acme;

import org.acme.pojo.CustomHttpRequest;
import org.acme.pojo.ResponseData;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class GreetingResource {

    @GET
    @Path("{pathText}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public ResponseData testContext(@Context CustomHttpRequest httpRequest,
                                    @PathParam("pathText") String queryText) {

       return ResponseData.builder()
                .queryText(queryText)
                .httpRequestText(httpRequest.getText())
                .secured(httpRequest.isSecured())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Here is the full example on GitHub: https://github.com/pkristja/resteasy_context/tree/main

I have found some alternatives that work with RestEasyReactive like using `ContainerRequestContext` and setting the data using setProperty.

Build file changes:
Changed from `implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-jackson")` to `implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson")`

Filter for setting oblect to context:

```
package org.acme.filter;

import org.acme.pojo.CustomHttpRequest;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Random;

@Provider
@ApplicationScoped
public class HttpRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Context
    ContainerRequestContext crContext;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
        CustomHttpRequest request = CustomHttpRequest.builder()
                .headers(requestContext.getHeaders())
                .dateTime(LocalDateTime.now())
                .text("Some random text for example " + new Random().nextInt(100))
                .build();

        crContext.setProperty("customHttpRequest", request);
    }
}
```

Retrieving object from context:

```
package org.acme;

import org.acme.pojo.CustomHttpRequest;
import org.acme.pojo.ResponseData;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class GreetingResource {

    @GET
    @Path("{pathText}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public ResponseData testContext(@Context ContainerRequestContext crContext,
                                    @PathParam("pathText") String queryText) {

        CustomHttpRequest httpRequest = (CustomHttpRequest) crContext.getProperty("customHttpRequest");

       return ResponseData.builder()
                .queryText(queryText)
                .httpRequestText(httpRequest.getText())
                .secured(httpRequest.isSecured())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Is there any way to get same functionality in RestEasyReactive like you had in RestEasy using `ResteasyContext.pushContext` because it's really verbose and inefficient to retrieve each object from context and cast it because in my real example I have multiple custom objects pushed to context with `ResteasyContext.pushContext`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using RESTEasy Reactive, there is a far easier way of doing things like this: just use a CDI request scoped bean.

Something like the following should be just fine:

```
@Singleton
public class CustomHttpRequestProducer {

    @RequestScoped
    @Unremovable
    public CustomHttpRequest produce(HttpHeaders headers) {
        return new CustomHttpRequest(headers.getRequestHeaders(), LocalDateTime.now(), "dummy");
    }
}
```

Then you would use it in your JAX-RS Resource as easily as:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String hello(@Context CustomHttpRequest customHttpRequest) {
    return customHttpRequest.getText();
}
```

Note that `@Unremovable` is only needed if you use `CustomHttpRequest`  as method parameter.
If you however inject it as a field, `@Unremovable` is unnecessary.

**UPDATE**

After https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/33793 becomes part of Quarkus (likely in 3.2) then `@Unremovable` will no longer be necessary even for the method parameter

Comment: So basically I can remove the filters now :D Thank you for quick response!